# NULL to 0 - PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Array that contains some entries. Some are string other are int. and those are defined in MySQL with type (int, varchar). The array i create looks like this: *(minified the array because too long)*

```
[3] => Array
    (
        [account_id] => *******
        [month_id] => 201903
        [month_comment] => 4,5% spend flat
        [month_spend] => 23000
        [month_budget] => 0
        [month_adops] => 1035
        [month_adops_forecast] => 1035
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [account_id] => ******
        [month_id] => 201905
        [month_comment] => 
        [month_spend] => 
        [month_budget] => 0
        [month_adops] => 
        [month_adops_forecast] => 45
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [account_id] => *******
        [month_id] => 201906
        [month_comment] => 
        [month_spend] => 
        [month_budget] => 0
        [month_adops] => 
        [month_adops_forecast] => 92
    )
```

As you can see some of `"month_spend"` and/or `"month_adops"` is empty, the problem is that in PHP the value is converted to "NULL" when the field is Integer in database, so result gives me:

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'month_spend' at row 2"
```

So i tried to change this inside an foreach loop like this:

```
$result_replace = array();
foreach ($data_replace as $key => $result) {
    $result['month_id'] = substr_replace($result['month_id'], '2019', 0, 4);
    if(empty($result['month_budget'])) {
        $result['month_budget'] = 0;
        $result_replace[] = $result;
    }
    else if(empty($result['month_spend'])) {
        $result['month_spend'] = 0;
        $result_replace[] = $result;
    }
}
```

but looks like the foreach loop does not edit the data?

Comment: So in an array of multiple elements there can be empty "month_budget" or "month_spend" or "month_adops_forecast" and "month_adops" but i cannot use OR because some object does have value in two variables and other 3 variables. what is the best way to insert 0 if empty on these fields. Maby i should rewrite my question

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you could update the data in place by adding `&` in `$key => &$result`.  This will change the original array rather then having to create a replacement array.

Comment: Please show the SQL query

Comment: Why should PHP cast a `0` coming from the database to `NULL`? Never seen that before. Additionally, please edit your question to add more details, do not use the comment section for that

Comment: In your SQL, you could use `IFNULL(month_budget, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Use following to check both instead of else if

```
$result_replace = array();
foreach ($data_replace as $key => &$result) {
    $result['month_id'] = substr_replace($result['month_id'], '2019', 0, 4);
    if(empty($result['month_budget'])) {
        $result['month_budget'] = 0;
    }
    if(empty($result['month_spend'])) {
        $result['month_spend'] = 0;
    }
    $result_replace[] = $result;
}
```

Comment: And if you want to also modify `month_adops` as mentioned in your question, just add an additional if :)

Comment: Worked like charm! i added more fields, is this a good practice?

Comment: Yes you can use if you have inconsistent data.

Comment: As your using `&$result` do you really need the `$result_replace` array?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
empty()
```

by

```
is_null()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value, $key){
        if(!isset($value) && ('month_spend' === $key || 'month_adops' === $key)) {
            $value = 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This could potentially set empty string values (i.e. month_comment) to 0.

Answer (score 0):

assumin your array is name $myArray

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $result) {
  if(empty($result['month_budget'])) {
       $myArray[$key]['month_budget'] = 0
  }
  if(empty($result['month_spend'])) {
         $myArray[$key]['month_spend'] = 0
  }
}
```

var_dump($myArray)

in your case you are just assignt an empty array to $result_replace nothing else

Answer (score 0):

1. `empty` from `0` will return false. So your code will be redundant with this function. Try to use is_integer. If not integer assign zero. The bad part is that you cannot avoid the loop with `foreach`.
2. is it possible to avoid the `foreach` from `php` by using a more concrete mysql query with e.g. `IF(ISNULL(your_column), 0, your_column)`.